# Chart.Js radar - hide label numbers

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to remove the displayed numbers on the radar from the library [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) (v3.7).

I've already tried to set the `legend` option to `display:false`

```
plugins: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    }
}
```

But it only hide the dataset label. If someone have the solution for it, I would be grateful to him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labels on the outside can be removed by setting the display option to false in `options.scales.r.pointLabels.display`. The tick marks in the middle can be hidden by setting the display options to false in: `options.scales.r.ticks.display`

```js
const options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        pointLabels: {
          display: false // Hides the labels around the radar chart 
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false // Hides the labels in the middel (numbers)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Work perfectly, problem solved. thanks !